# RealmSwift 10.15.1 not saving entries created by users

Tags: swift, database, realm, xcode12

I am using RealmSwift 10.15.1 to save user generated content in database. When a user creates and saves an entry, it saves in database but after a few days that data gets lost.
Can someone help me what could be causing this loss of entries after a few days or months?

Comment: Without knowing how you architected your app it would be impossible to help you. I would suggest putting as much info in your post as possible and be as clear as you can. How are you storing/deleting/modifying your data. What do your models look like? What does your code looks like? What have you tried to fix this problem?

Comment: What could be causing it is a coding error - you're probably overwriting the data at some point but without seeing your code, it's impossible to guess. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.